# get default Windows text editor .exe path using c++

Tags: c++, default-programs

Just wanted to know how to get default Windows text editor .exe path c++. I badly need this to improve one of my c++ assignment. I've no idea how to do it.

Comment: [It's unlikely that you really should have to do this, what's your actual problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If you just want to open a .txt file (or any file) with its default program on Windows, you can just use the `system` function and pass the path to the file as the only argument.

Comment: I just want to get the default program path of a specific file type. In this instance I'm dealing with .txt file types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way would be with [`FindExecutable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

If you require it to open files, then you can use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `edit` (or `open`) verb to get everything done all-in-one, else you can use [`SHAssocEnumHandlers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762109%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the handlers for the text based files you are interested in.

In the most simple case, you can also use `%windir%\\notepad.exe` which will link to notepad on any desktop version of windows.